# R randomly assigning to groups with conditions

Tags: r, random, data.table, grouping, assign

I would like to make a football world cup group stage draw generator, i.e. I have four pots with 8-8 teams with their names and their confederations, these teams needs to be randomly assigned to 8 groups from A to H and in each group should be 4 teams. I thought about assigning letters with the LETTERS() and sample() functions but the problem is that no group can have more than one team from any continental confederation with the exception of UEFA, which can have no more than 2 teams in one group. My pots are looking like this one pot:

```
           Team Confederation
1:        Ghana           CAF
2:       Serbia          UEFA
3:      Nigeria           CAF
4:      Morocco           CAF
5: Saudi Arabia           AFC
6:   Costa Rica      CONCACAF
7:     Colombia      CONMEBOL
8:        Chile      CONMEBOL
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Here you can see a manually constructed table to see that it is possible to construct such a grouping I need with the number of confederations.

```
          A        B        C        D        E        F        G        H
1:      AFC     UEFA CONMEBOL CONMEBOL     UEFA     UEFA     UEFA     UEFA
2: CONCACAF     UEFA      AFC     UEFA     UEFA     UEFA      AFC     UEFA
3:     UEFA      CAF      CAF      AFC CONMEBOL CONCACAF     UEFA      AFC
4:      CAF CONMEBOL     UEFA      CAF      CAF      AFC CONMEBOL CONCACAF
```

Comment: Is there any confederation with 5 or more teams? If so, as 5 > 4, you will have at least one team nowhere to go based on your conditions.

Comment: Yes, but see the updated post, if I could construct manually such table, I am sure that R should be able to do so as well.

Comment: what are restirctions on pots?

Comment: Could you post your data for the pots? Use `dput()` or the `reprex` package